# Seeing images lighter in FF vs IE

Tags: css, image, firefox

Open your favorite photo site in IE and FF.  Compare the two.  All of the images in FF are lighter - an almost foggy effect.

Looking around the net some people had issues in the past where the FF zoom needed to be reset - that is not the case.

Has a change been made to FF?  Is there a magic CSS setting that needs to be made for non-IE images display?

Really at a loss here.  The images on my client sites have not changed in many months.

Comment: What version of FF and IE are you talking about? And is this a vanilla install or one with a lot of other stuff? And what does this have to do with programming?

Comment: Make sure you are using a CSS reset style - without it, you might get some unwanted "default" settings from a browser.

Comment: Comparing images in ff8 v ie8 I see no difference in any site I've checked. Can you attach a screenshot or specify the sites you are comparing?

Comment: This is just a crazy stab in the dark, but do you have a dual monitor setup?  Do you have FF on one monitor and IE on the other?  What happens if you switch the two?

Comment: This may be a matter of the image being tagged with a color profile, and one of the browsers correcting the output and the other not. See, for instance, http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/color-correction/

Answer (score 0):

Just run the image through [smushit](http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/), to remove the color profile data. This will fix your problem.